# Android EditText 3.5 lines

Tags: android, android-edittext, lines

> I have to show max 3.5 lines in my EditText if lines are more then 3.
>   I tried lots of property but still not able to implement that.
>
> If a set android:layout_height="wrap_content" it will show N number of
>   lines.
>
> Do we have any property combination or I'll have to do it
>   manually.
>
> Say I fixed some height to android:layout_height="36dp" and
>   if line count is >= 4 again I have to set android:layout_height="48dp"
>   in this way i'll achieve what I am looking for.

**EDIT**

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){                    
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp  = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) txtMessage.getLayoutParams();
    if(txtMessage.getLineCount() > 3){
        if(lp.height != 0) {
            txtMessage.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        }
    }else if(lp.height != ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT){
        txtMessage.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    }
}
```

show at least 3 lines for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`android:maxLines="3"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines) to force the `EditText` to show no more than 3 lines.

But for 3.5, you can only do this by manually setting `EditText` height.

Comment: .@Gorcyn i tried android:maxLines="3"/setMaxLines(3) but don't know why its not working...

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? This property is supposed to stuck `EditText` display to 3 lines. But it doesn't stop user from typing much more. It that the problem?

Comment: No i mention android:layout_height="wrap_content" with android:maxLines="3" and setMaxLines(3) despite it keep growing...EditTest Height

Comment: Argh! I forgot it was an `EditText`! So! Did you add the `textMultiLine` flag in the `android:inputType` attribute too (as mentioned in the link in my answer) ? Without it it won't work.

Comment: Sorry! but i included android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences", android:maxLines="3" and txtMessage.setMaxLines(3); but still having the same problem

Comment: Strange it is... You should add Device and API version to your question so we can all help you

Comment: .@Gorcyn, i found that in my code EditText is having focus listener and on focus gain and lose setSingleLine(false)/setSingleLine(true) get called respectively which causes maxLines not to work. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

**Use below code for Edittext**

Use `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` and `android:lines="3"`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="3" />
```

Comment: .@Sandeep  android:lines="3" cause EditText height to be 3 line tall from start itself despite actual number of input lines